# Run HDFS as sudo user

Tags: bash, ubuntu, hadoop

Due to a script I am using to install Hadoop, I am having to run all commands as sudo. I am trying to start HDFS by typing "start-dfs.sh", but it says

```
sudo: start-dfs.sh: command not found
```

I typed the full path name i.e. sudo /home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.2.0/sbin/start-dfs.sh, but that did not work either. Does anyone know how I can start the  HDFS service as sudo? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try **sudo sh** before the full/absolute path of the script file..

Comment: it throws a weird error - hadoop-2.2.0/sbin/start-dfs.sh: 82: /home/cloud-user/hadoop-2.2.0/sbin/../libexec/hadoop-config.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Comment: To whoever downgraded the question - do you mind telling what was wrong about the question? I am sure there are plenty of people out there who do not know how to run HDFS as sudo.

Comment: Could you please try with **sudo bash** before the script file..seems like a shell issue...give a try and let me know...

Comment: I don't get what is happening, when I use sudo bash, a warning appears: [OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /home/cloud-user/hadoop-2.2.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so.1.0.0 which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now. It then tries to resolve each word in that warning...so things like "have: ssh: Could not resolve hostname have: Name or service not known" are appearing..I have no idea..